# Passing a function as parameter in an Angular Directive doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, parameters, frontend

I'm new in angular and I'm trying to connect two isolated directives under the same controller. My project is about a product store; the first directive shows all available products in a list with a button, the second shows the information with details. Workflow should be this: when I click on the button of a product the detail information should be reloaded with the content of the choosen product.

I think I've done all the conections needed, but it still doesn't work, when I click the button nothing happens... Here are my declarations:

- Main.html

  ```
  <div ng-controller="ProductController as productCtrl">
  <product-list data=productCtrl.productList></product-list>
  <product-details title={{productCtrl.activeProduct.title}} img={{productCtrl.activeProduct.imgSrc}} activator="productCtrl.setActiveProduct(p)"></product-details>
  <div>
  ```
- ProductList.js

  ```
  'use strict'

  angular.module('angularTestAppApp')
    .directive("productList", function(){
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope:{
          data: "=",
          function: "&activator"
        },
        templateUrl: 'views/ProductList.html'
      }
    });
  ```
- ProductList.html

  ```
  <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="product in data">
          <th scope="row">
            <button class="btn btn-info glyphicon glyphicon-play" ng-click='function(product)'></button>
          </th>
          <td>{{product.title}}</td>
          <td>{{product.price | currency}}</td>
          <td>
            <img ng-src={{product.imgSrc}} width=15%></img>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  ```
- ProductController.js

  ```
  'use stricts'

  angular.module('angularTestAppApp')
    .controller('ProductController', function(productListService) {

      ...

      this.activeProduct = {
        "title": "Hymn for the Weekend",
        "imgSrc": "images/hymn.jpg",
        "price": "2"
      };

      this.setActiveProduct = function(p) {
        this.activeProduct = p;
        console.log('Active product ' + this.activeProduct);
      }

    });
  ```

Any idea?

Thanks for all :)!

EDIT: The problems were:
 - 1: The argument was in the wrong directive.
 - 2: I was writing bad the function, to set parameters you need to bind the data by this way:

```
    ng-click='function({product:product})'

Instead of 

    ng-click='function(product)'

Calling in the HTML directive by this way:

    <product-list data=productCtrl.productList activator="productCtrl.setActiveProduct(product)"></product-list>
```

Thanks for your help :).

Comment: Are you using a `product-details` directive? Can you post a sample code for that directive?

Comment: function is a reserved keyword and your productDetails directive is missing. Is it possible to create a fiddle?

Comment: Sorry, the problem was that I was setting the argument in the weong directive and writting bad the argument of the function. Thanks for reply! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 issues,

- You are not passing `function="expression"` to the `production-list` directive
- The `&` expression works on the scope, so the function must be defined in the scope

```js
'use strict';
angular.module('angularTestAppApp', [])
angular.module('angularTestAppApp')
  .directive("productList", function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        data: "=",
        function: "&activator"
      },
      template: '<table class="table"><thead><tr><th></th><th>Name</th><th>Price</th><th></th></tr></thead><tbody><tr ng-repeat="product in data"><th scope="row"><button class="btn btn-info glyphicon glyphicon-play" ng-click="function({product:product})"></button></th><td>{{product.title}}</td><td>{{product.price | currency}}</td><td><img ng-src={{product.imgSrc}} width=15%></img></td></tr></tbody></table>'
    }
  });

angular.module('angularTestAppApp')
  .controller('ProductController', function($scope) {

    this.productList = [{
      title: 1,
      price: 1
    }, {
      title: 2,
      price: 2
    }];

    this.activeProduct = {
      "title": "Hymn for the Weekend",
      "imgSrc": "images/hymn.jpg",
      "price": "2"
    };

    var ctrl = this;
    $scope.setActiveProduct = function(p) {
      ctrl.activeProduct = p;
      console.log('Active product ' + ctrl.activeProduct, ctrl);
    }

  });
```

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="angularTestAppApp">
  <div ng-controller="ProductController as productCtrl">
    <product-list data="productCtrl.productList" activator="setActiveProduct(product)"></product-list>
    <pre>{{productCtrl.activeProduct}}</pre>
    <product-details title={{productCtrl.activeProduct.title}} img={{productCtrl.activeProduct.imgSrc}} activator="productCtrl.setActiveProduct(p)"></product-details>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh my god! The first issue is like a joke, I was setting the parameter in the wrong directive! (sorry for that). I didn't understand very well why do you need to set the function of the controller in the $scope, if I do that the function is never fired, however if I set it to the controller everything works fine :).

The problem was that when I set the parameter to the function in the HTML the format was wrong, here is what I modified:

    function({product:product})

Being "product" the parameter in the top HTML (activator="productCtrl.setActiveProduct(product)">).

Thanks for your help :D!